# How to build a custom function that uses externally defined values with a string condition in R

Tags: r, function, nested, switch-statement, apply

I'm working on a function for calculations of a single numeric variable (double). It should takes it's components from another data frame that stores different equations which are broken up into their single pieces (I use linear regression equations here so it's about the two variables/columns slope and intercept).
Depending on one condition (a name/specific string) which is stored in the equations table as well the function should use the slope and intercept from the same row.

The actual input data for the calculations comes from another dataframe stored in a numeric column.

The background: every condition requires a different equation and there are too many to come them into single functions.

I guess the function should follow this basic scheme:

```
data_conversion(numeric_input_data, "equation_id")
```

After trying to find a solution online, I experimented with forms of the apply-, subset-, ifelse- and switch-functions but was not successfull.

At the end I would appreciate a simple way, trying to avoid loops etc. if possible.

```
#create dataframe with equation parameters
equation_id <- c("eq_1", "eq_2", "eq_3", "eq_4", "eq_5")
slope <- c(1.1627907, 1.6949153, 1.2658228, 0.9345794, 0.9433962)
intercept <- c(-26.4069767,  -0.4067797, -27.3544304, -21.2336449, -22.9245283)
eq_df <- data.frame(equation_id, slope, intercept) 

#create some test data
group <- c("A", "B", "C", "A")
iso_value_p <- c(14, 12, NA, 13.5)
data_df <- data.frame(group, iso_value_p) 

#function [not working]; using iso_value as input for x
data_conversion <- function (x, choose_equation) {
  switch(choose_equation,
        eq_df[eq_df$equation_id == choose_equation, ] = { 
        res <- eq_df$slope * x + eq_df$intercept 
    }
  )
  return(res)
}
```

The function should work this way:

```
#for the first data row and the first equation
data_conversion(14.0, "eq_1")

#which should go like
1.1627907 * 14.0 + (- 26.4069767)

#result:
[1] -10.12791

#if I choose the second equation: 
data_conversion(14.0, "eq_2")

#which should go like
1.6949153 * 14.0  + (-0.4067797)

#should give:
[1] 23.32203

####and using the whole dataset togehter with "eq_1" should give:
data_conversion(iso_value_p , "eq_1")
[1] -10.127907  -12.45349  NA  -10.709302
```

But I did not manage to get the code working - the examples above are just assembled from 'manual' calculations of single values.

(PS: I'm a beginner in programming and R so please forgive me for my probably relatively imprecise description or if forgot something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that `eq_df` is present in the environment, we can create a function

```
data_conversion <- function(x, choose_equation) {
   inds <- eq_df$equation_id %in% choose_equation
   eq_df$slope[inds] * x + eq_df$intercept[inds]
}

data_conversion(14.0, "eq_1")
#[1] -10.12791
data_conversion(14.0, "eq_2")
#[1] 23.32203
data_conversion(iso_value_p , "eq_1")
#[1] -10.12791 -12.45349        NA -10.70930
```

This will also work if you pass two equations together. Combining 1) and 2) from above

```
data_conversion(14.0, c("eq_1", "eq_2"))
#[1] -10.12791  23.32203
```

However, it is better if we pass dataframe `eq_df` in the function as a parameter

```
data_conversion <- function(eq_df, x, choose_equation) {
   inds <- eq_df$equation_id %in% choose_equation
   eq_df$slope[inds] * x + eq_df$intercept[inds]
}

data_conversion(eq_df, 14.0, "eq_1")
#[1] -10.12791
```

Comment: Excellent, it work's fine! Thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Sorry for double posting. The answer lead to another questions regarding how to use  dynamic und multiple strings as an argument (for choose_equation): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55498710/building-a-function-that-dynamically-uses-externally-defined-values-with-a-strin