# Building a function that dynamically uses externally defined values with a string condition in R

Tags: r, function, nested, conditional-statements, grouping

This question derives from the question and answer given here:
[How to build a custom function that uses externally defined values with a string condition in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55485704/how-to-build-a-custom-function-that-uses-externally-defined-values-with-a-string/55485769#55485769)

The remark concerning the combination of 2 equations as an argument makes me curious and brings up 2 following questions:

1. How can I use multiple equations based on another string-value (a grouping variable) which I will add to the `eq_df`? (expected result: a numeric vector of differing length for each cell in `data_df$iso_value_p`)
2. If I store this grouping variable into the `data_df` as well, how is it possible to call for an equation (or several) which is/are matching this grouping variable in `eq_df`?

The code is the following one:

```
#create dataframe with equation parameters
equation_id <- c("eq_1", "eq_2", "eq_3", "eq_4", "eq_5")
slope <- c(1.1627907, 1.6949153, 1.2658228, 0.9345794, 0.9433962)
intercept <- c(-26.4069767,  -0.4067797, -27.3544304, -21.2336449, -22.9245283)
#add a broader group variable (e.g. size)
group_of_eq <- c("small", "medium", "medium", "medium", "large")
eq_df <- data.frame(equation_id, slope, intercept, group_of_eq) 

#create some test data
group <- c("A", "B", "C", "A")
iso_value_p <- c(14, 12, NA, 13.5)
#add a broader group variable (e.g. size)
group_broad <- c("medium", "medium", "small", "large")
data_df <- data.frame(group, iso_value_p, group_broad) 

#group_of_eq and group_broad should have spectra of levels that can be matched together

##[not working] (for question 1):
#Provided that eq_df is present in the environment, we can create a function
data_conversion_with_groups <- function(x, choose_group) {
  inds <- eq_df$group_of_eq %in% choose_group
  eq_df$slope[inds] * x + eq_df$intercept[inds]
}

data_conversion_with_groups(iso_value_p, "medium")
#[1]  23.32203 -12.16456        NA  22.47458
#it should return only 2 values (the 1st and 2nd row in data_df); and it gives an error-message:
#1: In eq_df$slope[inds] * x :
#  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
#2: In eq_df$slope[inds] * x + eq_df$intercept[inds] :
#  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I'm looking for the following:

For 1): For `data_conversion_with_groups(iso_value_p, "medium")` I would expect a vector with the length 3 (using 2nd-4th row in the `eq_df`).
Ideally they should each be coded into columns afterwards.

For 2): In case of the 1st row of `data_df` (that contains "medium" als value in the `group_broad` column) I would expect the same result. The difference is that here, that the group is called taken automatically.

Comment: If your argument `iso_value_p` is length 4, then the function will return 4, that's typically how vectorized functions (including `+`) work. The fact that the rest of the function does not try to limit `inds` to indicate exactly the same number of rows as `length(x)` is a logical problem, and one that I have no idea how to fix (since I don't understand what you're trying to do). Then you say *"3rd row in data_df"* ... but `"medium"` is in rows 2-4, not just 3.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct there was a typo within explantion at the end of the code (it is not the 3rd but the 1st and 2nd row; but iso_value_p ist a part of the data_df-dataframe and not of the eq_df-dataframe). The goal is to apply a linear regression function on iso_value_p. The second argument (here "medium") should call the correct regession equation (one or several), that is split up and stored in eq_df.  In case of "medium" it is 3 rows (2nd to 4th row).